# How to design a circuit with dual power source?

Tags: power

I have a LED that can be powered and controlled by a MCU (ATmega328) and would like it to be able to take power from battery.

[image: Circuit]

The battery (5 V) can be plugged or unplugged when needed, it's the secondary power source.
Requirements:

- When battery available led should use only its power source (5 V).
- When battery not available LED should use the power from MCU (3.3 V).
- The MCU should always able to turn on or off the LED.

How to design that? I will add the necessary resistor for the LED later.
Is it possible here the current go from B to C mixing voltage?

Thanks

**Update:**
Here is the @sai's answer circuit made from multisim.com
[image]

Comment: Is the battery 5V or 9V? In the first bullet point you mention 5V. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes you are right, that's a typo. I updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this.
[image]

You can adjust R1, R2 to get the LED brightness that you need for the 3.3V and 5V cases respectively.

R3 is to ensure that 5V goes to 0V completely when the battery is removed.

Choose a PMOS and NMOS whose RON is low enough (say few ohms or less) when VGS=3V

**Update**: I did the simulation in multisim and here are the results. Note that  I added another PMOS to take care of a case when 5V is available and the LED is OFF. Note that I also made the PMOS and NMOS much stronger than you so that they can carry higher current.

Case1: 5V OFF and LED OFF
[image]

Case2: 5V OFF and LED ON

[image]

Case3: 5V ON and LED OFF

[image]

Case4: 5V ON and LED ON
[image]

Comment: Do you have example of PMOS used at M1 and M2?  And what type of diode did you use on D1 and D3?

Comment: For the diodes you can use the 1N4148 that has been used in the other answers. M1 is an NMOS and you can use say AO3400. M2 is a PMOS and you can use say AO3401.   Instead of M1, you can also use a NPN transistor as has been used in the other answers.

Comment: I was trying to simulate this and got 1.5V on Led  (1.7V max with 1 Ohm resistors). My Led model have a minimal of 2.9V (green, blue) and 1.9V(red), I will use green only.

Comment: @Unicorn, how much current is flowing in the LED? What are the voltage drops across pmos and nmos? I assume this is the 3.3V case?

Comment: Between M2 and R1: 2.47V, R1 and Led: 1.7V, Led and M1: 863mV. Yes this is the 3.3V

Comment: @Unicorn, is the R1 =1ohm here? So, is the current 0.77A? I am a bit lost here. Current is so high but LED voltage is only 1.7-.863=0.837V. Is this the expected LED behaviour? I am not able to understand why you have so high current?

Comment: oops, I interchanged M1 and M2 sorry. Now It's fix and I got : including 5V => Between M2 and R1: 3.9V, R1 and Led: 4.0V, Led and M1: 3.4mV. Excluding 5V => Between M2 and R1: 1.9V, R1 and Led: 1.9V, Led and M1: 1.3V. I used 1k resistor for all. Is those values make sens?

Comment: @Unicorn, still not fully making sense to me. Voltage between M2 & R1 should be almost same as supply voltage. Voltage between LED and M1 should be almost close to 0V. Current in the LED should be what you have designed for. Voltage across the LED should be greater than the minimum diode voltage that your LED model mentions (LED voltage = R1-LED voltage minus LED-M1 voltage). Until all these 4 are true, we cannot say that your simulation is proper. Have you connected ground in your simulation testbench? Please add it to your question. It is not possible to debug the problem otherwise.

Comment: It's possible made wrong connections. I updated the question, I did not add schematic link because not offered on free version on that website.

Answer (score 3):

Design 1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP0pqF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D2 and D3 place node A at 0.7V less than the greater of the two potentials either side. If the 5V battery BAT2 is present, node A will be at +4.3V, otherwise 2.6V.

Q1 enables current to flow from A to ground, via the LED, only if the MCU output is high, regardless of the presence of BAT2.

This design has the problem that when powered from BAT2, the LED will be noticeably brighter, since there's only a single resistance controlling LED current, R1, which will obviously pass more current with the greater supply potential from BAT2.

In this next circuit I use Q1 not only to switch the LED on and off, but also to regulate current through it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI8Zsh.png)</sup>

R2 and R3 form a potential divider, placing about 1V at the base of Q1, when the MCU output is high. The base-emitter junction drops 0.7V, leaving only 0.3V across R1. The curent through R1 is \$I=\frac{0.3V}{47}\approx 6mA\$, almost all of which passes via the LED.

That current is *fairly* independent of either battery voltage, so the LED should glow with similar brightness regardless of the power source, and also regardless of the voltage of BAT2. There will be some variation, but much less that the previous circuit.

To set LED current \$I\$ through the LED, R1 is calculated like this:

$$ R_1 \approx \frac{0.3}{I} $$

Both of these circuits have a limitation. D2 will have 0.7V across it, and the transistor will also develop at least 0.2V (first circuit) or 0.5V (second circuit), leaving only a maximum of (3.3V − 0.7V − 0.5V) = 2.1V for the LED. Therefore you can probably only use red and green LEDs.

Comment: Thanks Simon for this, you did well to mention the color I found out mine actually need 2.9V minimum on green color. Without increasing the voltage of BAT1 is it a easy way to get my 2.9V? Probably I will end up to look for lower voltage RGB led.

Answer (score 3):

## Simplified backup circuit

The currents coming from the two sources in the Simon Fitch's figure 1 can be equalized also by adding a 330 ohm resistor R3 in series to BAT2 (I have modified and used their schematic). This trick is possible in this specific OP's circuit; in the common case, it is not correct.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV8qyY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To see how it works, first remove D2 and check the voltage of point A and the current through LED. Then restore D2 and remove D3; check again the voltage and the current. As you can see, the voltage difference is about 200 mV and the current is almost the same...

## Stabilized backup circuit

A BJT emitter follower has the "nasty" property of transferring the input voltage directly through the base-emitter junction to the load in the emitter when the collector voltage disappears. But here it can be useful if we connect the "backup" battery BAT1 as an input voltage source to the base and the "main" battery BAT2 (with 9 V, 5 V or other voltage) as a power supply. Let's see how the circuit operates in the two cases.

### Connected battery

In this case, the emitter follower is properly supplied and it copies the input voltage (3.3 V - 0.6 V) at the emitter. It does it by the help of the 9 V (5 V) power supply that makes its collector current flow through the load (the LED and R1 in series) and create an "opposing" emitter voltage. There is only small base-emitter difference and accordingly, small base current. As you can see from the next two schematics, the voltage across and, accordingly, the current through the load very weakly depend on the BAT2 voltage.

**9 V battery BAT2:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvverV.png)</sup>

**5 V battery BAT2:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYlzqY.png)</sup>

### Disconnected battery

Now there is no collector current flowing through the load and, accordingly, no "opposing" emitter voltage. The base-emitter junction, like a forward-biased diode, is fully turned on... and the 3.3 V (-0.7 V) input voltage is directly applied to the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw1Gsy.png)</sup>

Comment: There seems 100uA current flowing from 3.3V supply when the 5V supply is present. So, strictly speaking, it is violating the condition that "LED should only be using the 5V source when it is present"

Comment: @sai, That's right... but we can ignore it:-)

Comment: @Circuit fantasist, I just love that notion of using a transistor as an emitter follower when powered by 9v (thus getting regulation from it), and as a simple diode when 3.3V is the sole power source.  Too bad it consumes 0.6V of very limited headroom, but hey it works nonetheless

Comment: @Daniel Chisholm, Thanks for the nice response! I am just wondering why there are so few normal human reactions like yours here. Is it so hard to appreciate the other person's thinking and encourage it? I always do this... I will say some words about the idea but I have described it in detail in my [story](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/278933).

Comment: Thank you @Circuit fantasist and Simon Fitch also, for this great input and well detailed! Like said "sai" BAT1 should not be used at all when Bat2 is used, it's so elegant that I want to say come on, we can ignore it, but I'll think about it if I don't find better. For the moment I trust your value. I'll have to test it too, I'm not too used to the circuitlab's simulator. Thanks.